# jquery change div shape on click of button

Tags: php, jquery

i am showing user uploaded image into a div. there are four buttons for square, landscape, portrait and panoramic shape of div. user can change shape of div and according to div shape image set automatically. but i did not found any jquery or anything related to shapes. i want when user will click on square button div shape change according to this and same for landscape, portrait, panoramic. i have no idea how to start this. Please help. this is code and i have attached a screenshot. in this my image is not cutting according to height and width and it aligned left in place of center when i click on square.Please see the screenshot.
     $("#square").click(function(){

```
$(".resize-div").animate({width: 341,height: 341});


});
```

Comment: you will need to set the height and width of div on button click

Comment: can you please show me any example in jquery?

Comment: well you should be searching before asking such ques, many have given the answer to your ques already

Comment: but nothing is solving my problem.

Comment: can you show us, what you are exactly doing, paste some code

Comment: @user1523311 as far as i knw and i tried my answer is perfact wht u wnt...still u wnt something different shw us ur wrk

Comment: I have add the code and attached a  screenshot of uploaded image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `height width` according to your requirement

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnSquare").click(function(){
        $("#div").width(100).height(100);
    }); 

 $("#btnlandscape").click(function(){
        $("#div").width(300).height(400);
    }); 

 $("#btnportrait").click(function(){
        $("#div").width(400).height(300);
    }); 

 $("#btnpanoramic").click(function(){
        $("#div").width(100).height(100);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change dimentions of the div. For example:

```
var dim;

switch ($(this).data('type')) {
    case 'square':
        dim = {height: 400, width: 400};
        break;

    case 'landscape':
        dim = {height: 300, width: 400};
        break;

    case 'portrait':
        dim = {height: 400, width: 300};
        break;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z46Tt/2/

Answer (score 0):

onclick use  [Jquery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

and change the CSS properties of image Div. and make it square or whatever you want to make